# Python Caesar Cipher

Tags: python, arrays, encryption

I Am Trying To Make A Caesar Cipher In Python. The Code I Have Written Is Trying To Use An Array Then It Will Be Re-Arranged In A Iteration By The Amount Of The Key. I Am A Few Errors So Any Advice On How To Make The Array System Work Is Appreciated. Would This Idea Work Or Should I Give Up On This Method . Thanks
The Errors i Am Getting Are In The Key Subprogram With It Restarting If The Number Does Not =1-26

```
import sys

Alphbet =["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t"
,"u","v",",w","x","y","z"]

def Menu():
   print("Welcome To Password Protect Pc Optimizer 3000 Edition!")
   print("\n")
   print("1.) Encrypt A New Password And Save It")
   print("2.) Access An Existing Saved Password ")
   print("3.) Just A One Off Encryption ")
   print("4.) Quit Password Protect ")

   Answer= input("Please Enter An Option Number:")

   if Answer=="1":
       Key()
    elif Answer==2:
       Option2()
    elif Answer==3:
       Option3()
    elif Answer==4:
       Quit()
    else:
       Menu()



def Key():
    global Key

    Key = input("Please Set A Ceaser Cihper Key (1-26)")
    Validation =1
    if Key ==1:
        Validation +=1
        Option1()
```

Removed A Lot Of elif's Here

```
    elif Key ==26:
        Validation +=1
        Option1()

   if Validation ==1:
        print("Please Enter A Valid Number")
        Key()

def Option1():

    Hold=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18
","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26"]    

    for i in range(Key):
        Temp= Alphabet[Hold]
        Alphabet[Hold]= Alphabet[Hold-1]
        Alphabet[Hold-1] =Temp

    print(Alphabet)







Menu()'
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review [ask] and then [edit] your question. Be sure to include what errors, specifically, you're getting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem.

Comment: You don't have to go through all that trouble , the Caesar cipher is a siple substitution cipher . You can do your encryption with this line : `alphbet[ ( alphbet.index(letter) + rot ) % 26 ]` , and for the decryption , just change the '+' to '-'

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version:

```
from collections import deque
import string


class CaesarCypher(object):
    def __init__(self, cypher):
        encrypt_rotate = deque(string.ascii_lowercase)
        encrypt_rotate.rotate(-cypher)
        decrypt_rotate = deque(string.ascii_lowercase)
        decrypt_rotate.rotate(cypher)
        encrypt_trans = ''.join(encrypt_rotate)
        decrypt_trans = ''.join(decrypt_rotate)
        self.encrypt_table = str.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, encrypt_trans)
        self.decrypt_table = str.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, decrypt_trans)

    def encrypt(self, text):
        return text.translate(self.encrypt_table)

    def decrypt(self, text):
        return text.translate(self.decrypt_table)
```

First import `deque` to use its `rotate` method that will shift the elements position, then import `string` which contains the alphabet so we don't have to declare it.

Then create a class to encapsulate the encrypt and decrypt methods. Define a `__init__` method so the class will take an argument for the cypher and prepare the translation tables that will shift the characters.

Finally add 2 methods to the class to encrypt and decrypt based on the translation table.

Now you can use your class this way:

```
caesar = CaesarCypher(5)
test = caesar.encrypt('Hello World!')
print(test)
# > 'Hjqqt Wtwqi!'
test2 = caesar.decrypt(test)
print(test2)
# > 'Hello World!'
```

Edit:
This example only takes care of lowercase letters, if you want to encrypt uppercase you need to declare a separate table for `string.ascii_uppercase` and translate the text twice on the decrypt and encrypt methods, first for lower then for upper.

Edit2: If you are on python 2.7 the `maketrans` method is on the `string` class not in `str`. Thanks to @t.m.adam for the comment.

Comment: Just a minor thing , replace 'str' with 'string'

Comment: @t.m.adam: Why? we have 2 classes `string` is only for its `ascii_lowercase` so I don't have to declare the alphabet.

Comment: I mean this : `str.maketrans`

Comment: that statement is correct, I need the `maketrans` method of the `str` class

Comment: My fault , i use python 2.7 . +1 for your class